# Number of integer solutions of an equation $x^3 + y^2 = k$

Tags: number-theory, algorithms, integers

Given equation $$x^3 + y^2 = k$$
How can one count efficiently a number of integer solutions?

Comment: This question is interesting to the point that, it should be closed!

Answer (score 2):

If $(a,b)$ is solution to such an equation, $(-a,b)$ is solution of the Mordell equation $y^2=x^3+k$. There is not a general formula for the number of solutions of suchs équations, but you can find a lot of ressources about them on the internet.

Some examples of results :

- If $k=7,-5$ (but not only) there is no solution
- If $k=1$ then $(1,0)$ is the only solution

Some papers that may interest you : [EXAMPLES OF MORDELL’S EQUATION
KEITH CONRAD](http://www.math.uconn.edu/%7Ekconrad/blurbs/gradnumthy/mordelleqn1.pdf)
 and [THE MORDELL EQUATION
PETE L. CLARK](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/4400MordellEquation.pdf)